# Cdf of the joint density $f(x, y) = \frac{3}{2 \pi} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, joint-distribution

$$f(x, y) = \frac{3}{2\pi} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}, \quad x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$$

[image]

Find the cdf $F(x, y)$. To do this, we need to compute the integral

$$ \int_{-1}^{x} \int_{-1}^{y} \frac{3}{2\pi} \sqrt{1-u^2-v^2} dv du .$$

This is where I'm stuck. Converting to polar coordinates wouldn't seem to help since the area to be integrated isn't a circle.

**Edit**: Adjusting the limits of integration to

$$\int_{-1}^{x} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{y} \frac{3}{2\pi} \sqrt{1-u^2-v^2} dv du,$$

I tried using the substitution

$$v=\sqrt{1−u^2}\sin{\theta}, \quad dv=\sqrt{1−u^2}cos{\theta}d\theta$$

Then $\theta = \arcsin(\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})$, giving

$$\int_{-1}^{x} \int_{\arcsin(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})}^{\arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})} \frac{3}{2\pi} \sqrt{1-u^2-(\sqrt{1−u^2}\sin{\theta})^2} \sqrt{1−u^2}cos{\theta}d\theta du$$

$$=\int_{-1}^{x} \frac{3}{2\pi} (1−u^2) \int_{\arcsin(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})}^{\arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})} cos^2{\theta}d\theta du$$

$$=\int_{-1}^{x} \frac{3}{2\pi} (1−u^2) \int_{\arcsin(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})}^{\arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})} \frac{1}{2}[1+cos(2\theta)]d\theta du$$

$$=\int_{-1}^{x} \frac{3}{4\pi} (1−u^2) [\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)]_{\arcsin(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})}^{\arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})} du$$

At this point the integral got really messy to deal with. Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: You need to adjust your limits of integration such that you stay inside the unit circle.

Comment: At any point $X=x$ along the integral, you'll have to "sweep" from $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to the point $Y=y$.

Comment: Kudos to you for not giving up and holding off on accepting an answer that although thoughtful, it is more of a hint. I would suggest that you erase your comment (it's confusing because part of the $\LaTeX$ didn't come through), but paste it in an edit to the original post, so that people see your work.

Comment: This is an inherently messy integral.  One wonders how it arises in a statistical situation and whether there might not be a better way to model it.

Comment: @whuber Thank you so much for intervening. I think Sargis has shown a lot of interest and effort, and it was somewhat misleading to unwittingly insinuate there was an easy solution. I'm not sure, but I wonder if this cdf is handled numerically by Wolfram, for example: I get plausible answers with specific field values and just throwing out the imaginary component, but without a closed form. It is definitely a challenging problem that only superficially seems to call for polar integration.

Comment: @Antoni It looks simplest in polar coordinates.  Although there is a closed form, it takes several lines to write it down, in no small part because of how the expression changes depending on whether $(x,y)$ is inside the unit circle and on the signs of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem will be easier to solve if you first try and visualize what the joint pdf looks as a surface above the $x$-$y$ plane in three-dimensional space. Hint: ignoring the scale factor $\frac{3}{2\pi}$, what is the surface defined by 
$$z = \begin{cases}\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}, & x^2+y^2 \leq 1,\\
0, &\text{otherwise}, \end{cases}~~~~?$$ Can you think of ways that you might be able to compute the volume between this surface and the $x$-$y$ plane in the region $\{(x,y) \colon x\leq a, y \leq b\}$. The visualization will also help you set the lower and upper limits on the integrals as suggested by JarleTufto.